# When is it 'wrong' to put tabindex=0 on non-interactive content?

Tags: accessibility, tabindex

I'm trying to fix up a site made with the [adaptAuthoring](https://www.adaptlearning.org/index.php/adapt-authoring-tool/) tool after an accessibility audit. One of the audit items is a complaint about the very large number of tabs needed to navigate the document.

[Adapt sells itself on (amongst other things) accessibility features](https://www.adaptlearning.org/index.php/2017/05/17/is-accessibility-required/) and even WCAG compliance. I have my doubts. Maybe someone here can help me out.

I've noticed that almost all content generated by adapt authoring is given `tabindex=0`, even non-interactive content such as headings, lists and paragraphs. This does not seem like 'best practice' to me. It certainly requires dozens of additional tab-strokes to navigate documents made with the framework.

I've seen it mentioned in many places (especially including w3c documentation) that all **interactive** content should be available via tabbing, and that `tabindex=0` provides that functionality in those cases where the element is not focusable by default.

From that we might conclude that non-interactive content should **not** have the `tabindex=0` setting, although I have seen examples where (e.g.) ordinary paragraphs are given this setting.

As I understand it ['virtual mode'/'browse mode'](https://tink.uk/understanding-screen-reader-interaction-modes/) should be sufficient for reading text, and it's clear that the extra tabstrokes get pretty tiresome when browsing non-interactive content, not least because screenreaders often announce the type of the elements as well as the content, but I haven't found an explicit recommendation **not** to use `tabindex=0` in these cases.

So, did adapt do the wrong thing? If so, I want to file a bug with them.

Answer (score 11):

Adapt did the wrong thing for the right reason.  The [blog](https://www.adaptlearning.org/index.php/2017/05/17/is-accessibility-required/) you referred to had some great information.  Change the question from "Is accessibility required?" to "Is accessibility desirable?".  Based on their blog, they have a good concept of what accessibility **is** but their concept of **how** to implement accessibility isn't accurate.  They seem to think that those that need accessible accommodations should be segregated by turning on an "accessible mode".  As we know from just about any country's history, segregation is not a solution.

Their [accessibility page](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_framework/wiki/Accessibility) says:

> All Adapt courses have the accessibility feature built-in. However, it
>   must be enabled during development by the course author before the
>   course is published.

So, does the course author have to make the decision whether to turn that feature on or not?  Is it up to the course author to decide if accessibility is *desirable* (the word they used in their blog)?  Why is there an option to turn it on?  Why is it not always on?  Or rather, why is there an option at all?  The default should be to build an accessible interface.

That same option/segregation is offered to the end user too.

> To activate the accessibility feature while viewing a course, press
>   the Tab key. A button is displayed: "Turn accessibility on?" 
>   ...
>   Once the feature is activated, pressing the Tab key navigates the
>   learner through content. Focused content regions are highlighted with
>   an outline. And ARIA labels are enabled for assistive technology such
>   as screen readers.

What's different about the interface that requires accessibility to be turned on?  Any interactive object you can navigate to with the keyboard should **always** have a valid label or name (which is what ARIA labels give you if you can't provide a label/name with a native HTML element).  **Always**.  Why would you ever **not** want a valid name for an object?  You shouldn't have to turn that option on.

A user that requires a screen reader to interact with the page does **not** want to be treated any differently than a full sighted user.  They want to navigate to interactive objects using the TAB key just like any other keyboard user and they do **not** expect to tab to heading or paragraphs or lists or whatever.

Screen reading software has fantastic tools built in that allow for navigation to non-interactive elements.  You can press the 'H' key to go to the next heading (and hear it read), or for more granularity, press the '2' key to go to the next `<h2>`.  You can press the 'L' key to go to the next list, or the 'I' (eye) key to go to the next element in a list.  Press 'R' or 'D' (depending on the screen reader) to go to the next "landmark".  None of these elements are natively keyboard accessible and are not expected to be.  They should not have `tabindex="0"`.

Now, none of these shortcuts will work if the content author does not use native HTML tags that have built in semantic meaning.  That is, use

```
<h2>Really important info</h2>
```

instead of

```
<div class="big-bold-font">Really important info</div>
```

Screen reading software does not know that the "big-bold-font" class means the element should be a heading but it definitely knows what an `<h2>` is.  In the latter case, if you have to use a `<div>`, that's where ARIA attributes come in:

```
<div class="big-bold-font" role="heading" aria-level="2">Really important info</div>
```

With the correct semantic meaning, whether provided by native HTML tags such as `<h2>` or augmented by using ARIA attributes such as `role` and `aria-level`, a screen reader user can easily navigate to these elements without them having `tabindex="0"'`.

That's why I think Adapt understands what accessibility **is** but does not understand how accessibility is used.

So that's a really, really long answer (sorry) to what could have been a simple answer.  Your OP title is

> "When is it 'wrong' to put tabindex=0 on non-interactive content?"

**Answer:** Always.

Comment: [And I am not the first to notice!](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_framework/issues/2075)

Comment: @slugolicious, do you happen to have any good reference docs that say: Always wrong to put tabindex="0" on non-interactive content?

Comment: @morgs32 Yes, the official W3 doc on the `tabindex` attribute is defined at https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute and in the big "warning" it says "authors should only make elements focusable if they act as interactive controls or widgets"

Comment: This is one of those answers that makes me want to hammer on the upvote button repeatedly.

There are two major problems with a11y: People not taking it seriously, and people trying to be accessible, but doing it badly.  Putting `tabindex=0` on non-interactive content because you think that's how you can make it accessible is the latter.  It actually makes keyboard navigation _harder_ because you've got too many tabstops.

Comment: See also: https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-use-the-tabindex-attribute/#making-non-interactive-elements-focusable

Comment: *”This is one of those answers that makes me want to hammer on the upvote button repeatedly”*, thanks @daiscog

Answer (score 1):

> "When is it 'wrong' to put tabindex=0 on non-interactive content?"
>
> Answer: Always.

Someone should probably tell W3C that: [Feed Display example](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/feed/feedDisplay.html)

It's referenced in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Feed_Role) as well.

Not that I don't agree with you however: interactive elements shouldn't be focusable. However, there appears to be a lot of confusion around this topic, especially when you factor in WAI-ARIA guidelines as well.

**UPDATE:
[Here's another W3 example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-2/tabs.html) putting a tabindex="0" on an non-interactive element. The reasoning behind it stems from the fact that the content will otherwise be inaccessible to screen readers and other Assesstive Technologies.

Comment: The feed example specifically says *"This proposal does **not** yet have ARIA Practices Task Force consensus"*.  The "Update: another example" is the tab pattern and the tabs **are** interactive so correctly have `tabindex="0".